# CS50G Pong Project: Pong-2

Tags: lua, game-development, love2d

So in Pong-2 for the CS50G game development course, they use a function called love.graphics.clear() for their pong game. However, when I ran the program with this function, all I got was a giant white square in the middle of the screen. How do I get rid of it?
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzFov.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOIqh.png)

At first I thought that the rectangles were too big, and they made up that big rectangle in the middle. So after tweaking around with the love.graphic.rectangle() functions, nothing happened. However, when I got rid of love.graphics.clear(), I saw the rectangles, however the course used the same function and did not have the same problem.

Comment: Please share your code as a [mcve]. Thanks!

Comment: Recent versions of love uses a 0-1 color model. So you render a white box on a white background.